# How to VLOOKUP from bottom with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

Main Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j71MW_rgbWFxaldl4j4Ww3a22QMRZpy_u2NFrI1jjak/edit?usp=sharing

Formula in C155

IMPORTRANGE Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ADudSHKhcuPtoep-S8IDXuHXrid4T6RTRrJQT5htZcE/edit?usp=sharing

I found a link with info to reverse the table for `VLOOKUP` from the bottom (https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/vlookup-from-bottom-to-top-in-google-docs-sheets/), reason being I have multiple values of the same.  I always want to pull the latest value, which is at the bottom.

Current Formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C149 <= TODAY(),VLOOKUP(VALUE(C149),IMPORTRANGE("1g7AtubscrhkP2y6A0Dk7JUXiqxPhkSwKWlpeG7RVBKI","'South Loop Sales Log'!$A:$K"),2,FALSE),""),"")
```

Date Values are in column A for `IMPORTRANGE`.
Is there any way to implement this `VLOOKUP` formula to work with `IMPORTRANGE` also?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Updated with shareable links

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(C$149 <= TODAY(), VLOOKUP(VALUE(C$149), ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ADudSHKhcuPtoep-S8IDXuHXrid4T6RTRrJQT5htZcE", 
 "South Loop Sales Log!A3:K"), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(IMPORTRANGE("1ADudSHKhcuPtoep-S8IDXuHXrid4T6RTRrJQT5htZcE",
 "South Loop Sales Log!A3:A"))))}, 12, 0), 99^99, 11), ROW(A2), 0), ), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Unfortunately still sorting from top, updating question with sheet links.

Comment: @PeterChabot answer updated. now it does the exact reverse of importrange